# Default matrix value to zero in Power BI when no record exists for value

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am using Power BI Pro to generate a matrix table using month along the top, department name down the left and then a count of sales as the values.

In June we have a department that had no sales records for January so there is nothing to count.

How can I default it to show zero instead of blank?  I have used IF(ISBLANK()) on the sales id which has defaulted the sales values to 0 or 1 but because there is no record for june for that department it looks like IF(ISBLANK()) makes no difference.

**Screenshot**

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What does your current measure look like?

Comment: I think the issue is there is no record to run a measure against for that dept in June

Comment: Current measure looks like mSales = IF(ISBLANK([mCalcSales]),0,[mCalcSales]).  This measure uses mCalcSales which is CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(tbl[Id]), tbl[cSaleInd] = 1)